# Codeigniter: Ajax Request - Unable to Capture POST value or to return anything back to AJAX response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm having an issue with Codeigniter with the following symptoms.

1. When I send the data to the controller, I am unable to capture the POST data.
2. I've tried to echoed a simple word so I could return it back to the AJAX call and the responses are always null.
3. Since I am unable to capture the data in the controller, I cannot send it to the model which also returns null back to the controller.

I feel a little lost with this one.

Here's the sample code for the AJAX request. When I do this, I am able to see in the browser console that the "id" value is indeed being POST (id : 1).

```
var id = 1; //a simple test value to send to the ajaxtest function in the user controller.


$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '<?php echo base_url('user/ajaxtest'); ?>',
    data : {id : id},
    cache : false,
    success: function(res){
        var h = 'Another Test'; //just a test to add to the console.log along with the response.
        console.log({res, h});
    }
});
```

in the controller I defined the following function.

```
function ajaxtest() {
    //$res = $this->input->post('id');
    $res = $this->test_model->ajaxtest2();
    echo $res;
}
```

Now, before I get into the model, here's something else I've tried in the controller just to test the AJAX request.

```
//Tried to capture the POST value and echo back to the AJAX response but it goes back null. 
function ajaxtest() {
    $res = $this->input->post('id');
    //$res = $this->test_model->ajaxtest2();
    echo $res;
}
```

//Tried to send a value, still null ajax response.

```
function ajaxtest() {
    $res = '1';
    echo $res;
}

function ajaxtest() {
    //$res = '1';
    echo '1';
}
```

In the MODEL, I created this simple function (which is not working because for some reason I can't capture the ID value or send anything back to AJAX).

```
function ajaxtest2() {
    $res = $this->input->post('id');
    return $res;
}
```

I also tried returning a simple value and it doesn't do a thing.

```
function ajaxtest2() {
    $res = '1';
    return $res;
}
```

If anyone could shed some light, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please add an option in your ajax call because you are trying to send JSON data.

`dataType: 'json',`

That's your final call will be like the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '<?php echo base_url('user/ajaxtest'); ?>',
    data : {id : id},
    dataType: 'json',
    cache : false,
    success: function(res){
        var h = 'Another Test'; //just a test to add to the console.log along with the response.
        console.log({res, h});
    }
});
```

Comment: if I add dataType: 'json', to the ajax request then the response hangs and doesn't reach success. doesn't matter if the controller has echo json_encode($res); or just echo $res;

Comment: Yes, you need to do it like ```$this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode(array('foo' => 'bar')));``` or ```header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode( $arr );exit;```

Comment: Sorry, adding the header content type or using CI's content type set doesn't change the outcome after adding dataType: 'json'. still can't reach success.

Comment: It is the right method, I can tell you. But you see an error. Can you send me a screenshot 
 with errors on Google chrome console. Or can you check if there is a CSRF protection enabled in your CI configuration? If CSRF is enabled, it may cause error because you don't include any CSRF token on ajax call.

Comment: CSRF is disabled ($config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;) and yes, ajax's error handler is returning an error: SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Answer (score 0):

They have many way to test this :

1. Have you try to add `.error()` function in your ajax call?
2. Check to use `dataType` sended by ajax option : `dataType: 'json'` or `dataType: 'jsonp'`
3. Check if the URL was call is good. Check in the console if you don't have an error
4. Try to do `print_r($_REQUEST)` into your controller to saw Request elements passed into POST
5. If you saw `id` try to print `$this->input->post('id')`

Check https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for all reference functions and parameters

Try these elements and let us know if everything is working fine.

Just a note for jQuery :

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '<?php echo base_url('user/ajaxtest'); ?>',
    data : {'id' : id},
    dataType: 'json',
    cache : false,
    success: function(res){
        var h = 'Another Test'; //just a test to add to the console.log along with the response.
        console.log({res, h});
    }
});
```

When you pass data through ajax, it must be in Object type.Like, {'id' : id}.But in your code, you have given, {id : id}. Hope you understood the bug.

Comment: Thanks but that's not the case. it works either way and I am able to send the POST data, the problems is getting back a response from the controller and I just noticed that the problem seems to be WITH the "user" controller. I added the function to another controller and I was able to make the ajax request and get a response back. I have no idea why I can't get a response when using the "user" controller.